# Accept incoming L2TP connections on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, l2tp

Windows 2003 can be configured as a VPN server that uses L2TP with a preshared key.
Windows 7 can be configured to accept incoming VPN connections, presumably using PPTP.

**Is there a way to configure Windows 7 to accept incoming L2TP connections?** The configuration settings for incoming connections is extremely sparse; I don't see any place to enter a preshared key or specify the protocol to use. Perhaps it is beyond the capabilities of Win 7, but I hold out hope that I'm overlooking some Group Policy settings or registry edits that allow it.

Comment: This might be a little late but I just saw this guy doing that in WinXP http://rotwhiler.wordpress.com/2009/04/09/windows-xp-pro-as-a-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-server/ plus I see a rule in windows 7 firewall about allowing remote access through L2TP...

Comment: @Cristian - Wow, that might actually be the answer. I wonder if it works for Windows 7 as the VPN server? I ended up using Windows 2008 R2 as the server instead of Windows 7, otherwise I would try it out.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this is possible after all.

See this article : [How to Set up an incoming VPN on Windows 7](http://www.howtonetworking.com/VPN/win7vpn1.htm).

There is also a youtube video tutorial : [How To Setup VPN on Windows 7 as Home Solution](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1s5JxMG06L4).

Setting up an L2TP/SSL server on Windows 7 is not possible without third-party software.
The best known one is the open source [OpenVPN project](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html), where you should look at [Access Server](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as.html).
However, under Windows it is only available as a [Virtual Appliance VHD](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as/202.html?osfamily=Virtual%20Appliance%20Windows%20%28VHD%29&ex=1), to be used with Virtual PC.

Comment: I read the guide and watched the video. Unfortunately those steps result in a VPN connection that uses PPTP. I'm inquiring specifically for setting up a connection that uses the more secure L2TP protocol.

Comment: See my above edit.